# rest resource expose, fails when the request comes from another salesforce platform but not when it comes from a different platform such as postman

Tags: apex, rest-api

I have a rest resource in my org, where part of the logic requires before providing the response to do an API. Something in the lines of:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/something/*')
global without sharing class myclass {

    @HttpPost
    global static Map<String,String> create() {
        ... SOME LOGIC 

        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        String body = '....';
        req.setTimeout(120000);
        req.setEndpoint('https://www.something.com/');
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setBody(body);
        res = http.send(req);

        ... DO SOMETHING WITH res.getBody();      
        return ...
    }
}
```

This works fine when the API is initiated from any system that is not Salesforce. I can use Postman or any custom platform without any problems.

However, when the API is initiated from a Salesforce org in this case from a potential business partner who wants to send us some informaiton, we run into the error:

> Error 'System.CalloutException: Callout loop not allowed'

Based on this article (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000340086&type=1) it seems that this is an expected behavior and is done by design?

What is not clear for me is why it will not fail with other platforms and only fails if the callout is initiated by a different Salesforce platform.

How can I solve this, do I have to move this API outside of salesforce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce adds a magic header to any callout made during a callout in Salesforce called `Sfdc-Stack-Depth`. If Salesforce encounters this header during an API call, it immediately terminates the transaction with the specified error.

In other words, you would be allowed to make this callout from non-callout Apex (e.g. a @AuraEnabled method, in a Batchable class, etc), but you cannot make a call to a Salesforce callout from within a Salesforce callout. This is done to prevent potentially infinite recursion and runaway resource usage.

To allow the callout, do not make the callout from within a callout (e.g. @HttpPost or webservice methods). You might do this from a Lightning/Aura Web Component, a Queueable/Batchable class, Visualforce page, etc, you just can't do it when you're already in a callout.

Comment: I can see that header now, basically from what I see I have 2 options, as I dont have control on who is doing the request could be someone with salesforce or someone outside salesforce, will be sort of correct to say that I either move this API to an external system some sort of proxy or maybe a queueable?

Comment: @manza A queueable should work (don't forget Database.AllowsCallouts), or any other method that doesn't involve using a direct callout. An external server is also possible, if you absolutely need to.